# elastic exists query for nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested documents as:

```
"someField": "hello",
"users": [
   {
     "name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "age": 2
   }
]
```

according to this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html, the above should match:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists" : { "field" : "users" }
  }
```

}

whereas the following should not,

```
"someField": "hello",
"users": []
```

but unfortunately both do not match. any ideas?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The example mentioned on the Elasticsearch blog refers to string and array of string types, not for nested types.

The following query should work for you:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "users",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "users"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3495) for more info, which discusses this usage pattern.

Comment: Anyone knows why nested field DSL have to be designed such complex.

Comment: This query returns empty results for me.. Although in Discover mode I see documents with non-empty nested field. Help?

Answer (score 18):

This works for me

```
GET /type/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "outcome",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "outcome.outcomeName"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

With the following index mapping:

```
{
  "index_name": {
      "mappings": {
        "object_name": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
              "nested_field_name": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "some_property": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
              }
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I needed to use this query:

```
GET /index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "nested_field_name",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "nested_field_name.some_property"
                    }
                  }
              ]
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch version 5.4.3

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [user3775217](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775217/user3775217) has worked for me but I needed to tweak it to work as expected for `must_not`. Essentially the `bool`/`must` needed to be wrapped around the `nested` portion of the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "users",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "users"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shorter version**
(without bool query), (tested on ElasticSearch 7.x)

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "users",
      "query": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "users"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "users",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "users"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```